# How many factors should be used for a cluster analysis?

Tags: clustering

I have a short question. I've performed a principal component analysis and obtained two components. Are two components enough two perform a cluster analysis (number of participants > 400)? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: As many as neccessary. **Visualize your data.** If you can't see clearly cut clusters in 2d, then algorithms won't return meaningful results either.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to identify optimal number of clusters from the data, one way is to use [Consensus Clustering](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ml/biodm/papers/MLJ-biodm2.pdf) which performs repeated random sampling on the data, and identifies the number of clusters that has the most robust cluster membership across variables.

To answer your more question more directly, N top components should correspond to 2*N clusters in the linear space as each component represents variables correlated and anti-correlated with it.